# Why does select statement displays result in the result set of previous select statement inside stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i wrote a stored procedure to display prime numbers upto a limit and count of 'how many prime numbers are generated'. But when calling the procedure, it seems like the second select statement is returning its result in first select statements result set. it only happens inside a procedure. why? how to solve this? please help.

```
drop procedure if exists prime;

delimiter $$
CREATE procedure prime(in num int)
begin
   declare i int;
   declare j int;
   declare cout int default 0;
   drop table if exists temp;
   create table temp(prime_no int);
   set i=2;
   while i < num do
       set j=2;
       w1: while j <= sqrt(i) do
                   if mod(i ,j)=0 then 
                         leave w1;
                   end if;
                   set j=j+1;
       end while;
        if j>sqrt(i) then
          insert into temp values(i);
          set cout=cout+1;
        end if;
        set i=i+1;
    end while;

    set @prime_count=cout;
    select @prime_count as 'prime_count';
    select prime_no as 'prime_numbers' from temp;


end$$
delimiter ;
call prime(27);
```

```
and the output is 
+-------------+
| prime_count |
+-------------+
|           9 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.4541 sec)
+-------------+
| prime_count |
+-------------+
|           2 |
|           3 |
|           5 |
|           7 |
|          11 |
|          13 |
|          17 |
|          19 |
|          23 |
+-------------+
9 rows in set (0.4541 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.4541 sec)
```

** Look, there are two result sets, but both has same column header... whts d prblm here??**

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue are you running this via a ui? and nor can dbfiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6NZ4SCoezVr2hvdfRSSw7y/0

Comment: i am running it in mysql shell 8.0.12.. it works fine when running it in mysql workbench. But we are supposed to use shell during exams. How to solve this.